# Finder refuse to open shared files with Microsoft Office

Tags: ms-office, file-sharing, automount

We have a nfs share server mounted trough automount on which we store multiple `*.xls` files.

Since a few days, two MacBooks refuse to open those files with the following error message:

```
"file.xls" is damaged and can't be opened. You should eject the disk.
"file.xls" is on the network volume "name_of_volume". Microsoft Excel opened this network connection on 10 October 2018.
```

Every thing is ok on other Macbooks and worst if I go through, `Excel > File open...` it works...

Can anyone solve and explain this?